# PHP's crypt function (STD_DES) in javascript

Tags: javascript, des, crypt

Is there an implementation of the `crypt` function in PHP written in javascript?

I only need the STD_DES version eg.

PHP:

```
<?php
    echo crypt('test', 'SO') . "\n";
    // SOVYikZv1wMH.
?>
```

JS:

```
console.log(PHP_crypt('test', 'SO'));
// SOVYikZv1wMH.
```

I have tried to use [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js), but it doesn't seem to work the same way:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/tripledes.js">
</script>
<script>
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt('test', 'SO');
    console.log(encrypted.toString());
    // U2FsdGVkX1/VopEwWoWNH8SrvmdvM1O9
</script>
```

**Note:** I know DES is not secure, I shouldn't use it and X is way more secure than DES.

Comment: can [this](http://www.tero.co.uk/des/) help you? they have some [examples](http://www.tero.co.uk/des/show.php)

Comment: @vladkras I don't get the same result as above.

Comment: Steal the `descrypt` function from this site: http://dmr.ath.cx/misc/pwd/pwd.js

Comment: @Blender `descrypt('test', 'SO')` -> `TypeError: Cannot read property '116' of undefined`

Comment: @Blender ah, `des_init(); descrypt('test', 'SO');` works perfectly. Could you post this as an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: @Tyilo: It doesn't feel like a decent solution, as it's not portable and pretty messy. You're basically looking for a crypt(3) implementation in JS.

Comment: @Blender well here it is without the `md5` and other stuff: https://gist.github.com/Tyilo/5954072

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have copied the relevant part of the code from http://dmr.ath.cx/misc/pwd/pwd.js, where it is implemented.

Usage:

```
des_init();
console.log(descrypt('test', 'SO')); // => SOVYikZv1wMH.
```

The code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Tyilo/5954072).